Second Order LCCDE - BOOK; trying to find out the name of the book
I have found the following part of a book:
https://web.eng.fiu.edu/ANDRIAN/EEL3135/second%20order%20LCCDE.pdf
I would like to find out the entire book.
Do you have any idea how this book is called?

This is from Signals & Systems: Theory and Applications, by Fawwaz T. Ulaby and Andrew E. Yagle. A second edition of this book is available as a free PDF.
